# Multiple read access on Kinect v2, Docker

Tags: docker, kinect, libfreenect2

Sorry, I couldn't find a perfect title for my issue. I have the following situation:

I am doing body pose tracking, using a motion capturing system (http://openptrack.org/) which runs encapsulated inside a Docker on my Ubuntu 16.04. I am using a Kinect v2 with libfreenect2 (which runs inside the Docker of course).
Parallel to my body pose tracking, I want to implement a object pose tracking. I thought about Aruco-markers. For this I need access to the Kinect camera as well. When I try to sample camera images, my application and also the application inside the docker crashes.

So my questions are the following:

1. Inside the docker libfreenect2 is already running. Is it somehow possible to run libfreenect2 outside the docker as well and get access to the Kinect images?
2. Or is it somehow possible to access the sampled images which are lying inside the docker?
3. Is it possible to program and run my application inside the existing docker?

Sorry, if the questions are not super clear.

Thank you.